# C# Imap client - Use of expression trees

Tags: c#, lambda, imap, expression-trees

I am currently in the progress of developing my own .net imap api, I want to incorporate the use of expression trees in the imap SEARCH command, so for example:

```
client.Search(m => m.DateRecieved < DateTime.Now)
```

should be converted to the following

```
imap1 SEARCH SENTBEFORE 8-Sep-2011
```

Since I am not to familiar with expression trees is it possible to convert that func parameter into the specified command? I know I will have to check for each property of 'm' and check what is what but I am not quite sure where to start.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start define your search function as (assume m is a class called Splog):

```
void Search (Expression<Func<Splog, bool>> searchExpression)
```

Then the fun begins.

Then you can do stuff :

```
string comparison= "";
string compare1= "";
string compare2 = "";

if ( searchExpression.Body is BinaryExpression ) // Ensure the expression is a comparison..
{
    if ( searchExpression.Body.NodyType == ExpressionType.LessThan )
        comparison = "SENTBEFORE";
    else if ( searchExpression.Body.NodyType == ExpressionType.GreaterThan )
        comparison = "SENTAFTER";
    else  if ( searchExpression.Body.NodyType == ExpressionType.Equal )
        comparison = "EQUALS";

    // Then evaluate the left and right portions.
    if ( ( searchExpression.Body as BinaryExpression ).Left is MemberExpression )
         compare1 = ( ( searchExpression.Body as BinaryExpression ).Left as MemberExpression).Member.Name;

    if ( ( searchExpression.Body as BinaryExpression ).Right is MemberExpression )
         compare2 = ( ( searchExpression.Body as BinaryExpression ).Right as MemberExpression).Member.Name;

}

Console.WriteLine ( compare1 + " " + comparison + " " + compare2 );
```

**Note**

This is just to get you started. Things get complicated very quickly. Some things you have to bear in mind are :

1. Nothing in an expression gets evaluated. So in your example if you pass the expresssion `x < DateTime.Now`, DateTime.Now is not evaluated to a Date. You are passed a PropertyExpression for the Now property of DateTime. You would need to cater for this and evaluate to get get the current date.
2. The example assumes you have a simple binary comparison. It will not cater for a more complex comparison like `(m.DateReceived < DateTime.Now && m.Client == "Spog" ) || m.Ooofgle > 22932`

To handle more complex scenarios like this you should make sure your method works down the tree recursively to build up your expression. Its a lot of fun and a good exercise.

Read through the [Expression documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx) thoroughly.

Comment: Wow this is fantastic. Expressions trees look amazingly powerful. Thanks!